# Why should we need an primary key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, primary-key

Why would I need a *primary key* for a table to be mapped with *Entity Framework* in *C#*, I need to know why primary key is mandatory while using EF.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework needs a primary key. However the database underneath doesn't. I'm guessing it was a design consideration to do with navigation properties and Code First. With Database First you can probably get away with it.

---

The *Primary Key* concept is critical to an efficient *Relational Database*. Without the primary key and closely related foreign key concepts, relational databases would not work. *EF* is backed by a *Relational Database* of some type.

Here are **some** of the fundamental reasons why relational DBs need *Primary Keys* (PKs):

- In order to relate a *Parent Table* to a *Child Table*. This is part of the principles behind relational databases in a principle called *Third Normal Form (3NF)*. There are other *Normal Forms* you can research.
- In order to migrate the parent table key to the child table as the *Foreign Key* (FK). This eliminates the need to duplicate information from the parent table into the child table. The parent table could be a reference code table OR an operational data table
- To enforce *Referential Integrity* (RI), which requires the use of PKs.
- To ensure *Data Integrity* (DI), an RDBMS construct. RI prevents deletion of parent keys that are still being referenced, orphan rows etc.